# could somebody tell me how to read 10 bytes with 1 byte long buffer?

Tags: linux, file, assembly, buffer

could somebody tell me how to read 10 bytes with 1 byte long buffer?

my programming environment is ubuntu linux, emacs, assembly, at&t syntax

I can read file and save read data to buffer(1byte)

but how can I read next 1 byte of file and save to buffer?

I edit the content to paste my effort

```
.section .data

    .section .bss
    .lcomm buffer,1

    .section .text
    .global _start

_start:
    movl %esp,%ebp
    subl $8,%esp
    #8(%ebp) is 2nd arg == input
    #12(%ebp) is 3rd arg == output

    #open,read,open,write,close
    movl $5,%eax
    movl 8(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $0,%ecx
    movl $0666,%edx
    int $0x80
    #%eax contains input's fd
    #movl to first local var
    movl %eax,-4(%ebp)

    movl $5,%eax
    movl 12(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $03101,%ecx
    movl $0666,%edx
    int $0x80
    #eax contains output's fd
    #movl to second local var
    movl %eax,-12(%ebp)

    #read 1 byte from file 1st byte of data
    movl $3,%eax
    movl -4(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $buffer,%ecx
    movl $1,%edx
    int $0x80

    #read 1 byte from file I expect 2nd byte of data
    movl $3,%eax
    movl -4(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $buffer,%ecx
    movl $1,%edx
    int $0x80

    #buffer contains 1 byte of file
    subb $48, buffer
    movl buffer,%ebx
    movl $1,%eax
    int $0x80
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use C? Or failing that, to call `read()` from your assembly code?

Comment: thank you for your replying.

but I want to implement in assembly.

because it is good to understand how it works

Comment: why don't you make an effort first?

Comment: how are you reading the single byte now?  You must be using some kind of system call, right?

Comment: Hmm.. If you want to store 10 bytes in memory using 1 byte long buffer then it seems impossible to me. But if you want just to READ bytes (iterate through them) then what's a problem? Just read the next byte like the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ nasm -f elf -o test.o test.nasm
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ ld -o test test.o
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ ./test
0  # this is what I typed
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ 
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ echo $?
48
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.nasm
global _start
_start:
 push eax ; for buffer
 mov ecx, esp
 mov edx, 1 ; # bytes to read
 mov ebx, 0 ; stdin
 mov eax, 3 ; read
 int 0x80
 mov ebx, [ecx] ; what we just read
 mov eax, 1 ; exit
 int 0x80
```

you still need to set up the loop for your 10 chars and convert to ATT syntax, but this ought to get you started.

Comment: thank you all of you. the things that I don't know is where to put index(offset) when I want to start to read in the middle of file. eax for system call number, ebx for file descriptor, ecx for address of buffer, edx for size of buffer. 1st byte of data -> 1 byte buffer. it is ok. but 2nd byte of data -> 1 byte buffer, how to?

Comment: oh sorry it's my input file mistake. when I try as above code I paste, it reads 2nd byte of data! thank you for your helping anyway